# How to use Yii 2 Lajax ToggleTranslate

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I searched in documentation how to turn on ToggleTranslate on Yii 2 but with no success. I echoed widget

```
<?= \lajax\translatemanager\widgets\ToggleTranslate::widget(); ?>
```

but it does not apper. Then I went to source code and got this:

```
if (!Yii::$app->session->has(Module::SESSION_KEY_ENABLE_TRANSLATE)) {
    return;
}
```

I commented it and my button appeared. But button is not working. So my question is how to properly (by proper flow, by proper guide) configure it and run it?

Comment: Have you done everything like it says at https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager ? Either you set `roles` parameter and you are signed in with role with no access or you try to run this on remote server without proper `allowedIPs` config.

Comment: @Bizley i loged in (Dektrium user module) and my role is `admin` and my config is [this](https://paste.kde.org/pthyavy68)

Comment: @Bizley i think this is becase of this `Module::SESSION_KEY_ENABLE_TRANSLATE` constant, any ideas, how do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure if Dektrium RBAC is compatible with default way of checking role access... When you remove role `admin` limitation is it still not showing?

Comment: @Bizley I commented this `'roles' => ['admin'],` (in common/config.main `modules => [' translatemanager' => [] ]`) and it still not showing

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. Have you add [this part](https://github.com/lajax/yii2-translate-manager#front-end-translation) in your config? Also you have got `urlRules` in `modules` section which is wrong but not related to this problem.

Comment: @Bizley yes, i have add it and it's still not working

Comment: Have you tried to add `authManager` component configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131785/discussion-between-link-and-bizley).

Answer (score 0):

Site controller I modified:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            /** set session key for appearing translate button */
            if(array_key_exists('admin', Yii::$app->authManager->getAssignments(Yii::$app->user->id)))
                \Yii::$app->session->set('frontendTranslation_EnableTranslate',1);
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```